# Functioning of jQuery post() with show/hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm calling a Python script through a Javascript function that uses the jQuery post() method, like this.

```
function onChangeTitularInfraestructura(val) {
            if (val=='10') {
                $.post("/folder_1/pyscript/getSelectTitularInfraestructura", {name:'f_titular_infraestructura',value:val, all:'',styleclass:'form-element',empty:'True' }, function(data) {
                    $('#div_titular_infraestructura').html( data );
                }).fail( function(){ $( "#div_titular_infraestructura" ).html( "Internal Server Error" ); } );

                $('#div_titular_infraestructura').show();
            } else {
                $("#div_titular_infraestructura").hide();
            };
        };
```

And it's working as it was intended to, that is: if I click on that value (10) of the dropdown that calls the onChange, another dropdown (built by the python script) appears; otherwise, the div is hidden.

I have a question, though: if I don't write the line with the `show()` method, it doesn't work as expected. If I select value 10 at the first click, it appears, if I choose some other value it disappears (and it's ok, so far), but if I choose again value 10, it doesn't appear again, it remains hidden.

What's the explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Initially your div **`div_titular_infraestructura`** does not contains any value, therefore it seems like it is hidden. When you first select **10** then value gets populated in that div and it appears to be visible.

When you select other value it hides the div, setting it's **display** style to **none**, therefore when you select value 10 without **`show()`** method this property(display) does not get switch and it remains hidden.

With **`show()`** method **`display`** sets to **`block`** and it becomes visible on the screen.